# c# foreach loop - issue

Tags: c#, for-loop, foreach

```
List<Student> studentList = new List<Student>();

Student s = new Student(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text, loc );

foreach (String subject in listBox1.Items)
{
    string[] key_value = subject.Split('-');
    s.subjects.Add(key_value[0], Double.Parse(key_value[1]));
}

// subjects is a dictionary of subject name, and grade.
```

I need to make more than one student but the problem is that `key_value` is defined `[0][1]` and it lets me make just one student. How can I make that value increase each time I enter one student?

Comment: Can you rephrase your requirement? do you want to loop through students and subjects to student collection? or loop through different subjects for each student?

Comment: `studentList.Add(s)`?

Comment: I'm making student list and they all should be stored in listbox with their informations (fName, lName,averageGrade...) so I need to loop through different subjects for each student I guess. I'm rookie at this.

Comment: quite unclear what are you asking.

Comment: where do you declare / define listbox? here is a hint
`The trick to ListBox Displaying data is -- the DisplayMember, and the ValueMember.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an counter and increment it  in each loop.

```
int i = 0;
foreach (String subject in listBox1.Items)
{
    string[] key_value = subject.Split('-');
    s.subjects.Add(key_value[i], Double.Parse(key_value[i]));
    i++;
}
```

**update** I edited the i+1 from `Double.Parse(key_value[i+1])`, as this will throw an index out of range exception. I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to do with this here.. if you edit your question, I'll be sure to update my answer to give you a working solution.

Comment: With all due respect here, this is not a valid answer, even if we take into account that the question is just as flawed. Unless through some strange accident that the listbox items contain a large number of '-' characters, this code will immediately cause an IndexOutOfRangeException whenever listBox1 contains more than one  item.

Comment: Additionally what I don't get here is: You are iterating through the items in the listbox, but each time you take another part of the array that the specific iteration has? What for? That doesn't make much sense there although that is more @kadja

Comment: @MrsEd what you did is exactly what the OP asked for so your original answer is ok. which is the reason why I put the at symbol with the OP there and not you as his definition does not make sense but you fullfilled it with your solution

Comment: @MrsEd (helping with) solving a question isn't a problem in my view even if the question is flawed. Often even when reading compltely through things and mulling over it it can happen that an answerer overlooks things that is why we have a community here so that even strangenesses like this current ops get noticed more easily. So I wouldn't take it too hard. Can happen and does happen, so whatever ;) and as long as the OP is helped and also gets pointed out that he has a flaw in his basic idea by someone all is fine anyway :)